# How does one properly write the following nested For Each loops?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

So, I have a data sorting problem. Essentially, I must sort the cells of row 2 beneath their approximate values in row 1.

The data will often appear as this:

[image: Mismatched]

But I require the data of Row2 to be sorted beneath its Row1 counterpart in approximate value (within 1.2 of it), like this:

[image: Sorted]

I believed the best way to accomplish this was to create a nested set of For Each loops, as written below:

```
Dim F As Range
Dim Q As Range

For Each F In Range("A1:C1")
    For Each Q In Range("A2:C2")
        If Q.Cell.Value <= (F.Cell.Value + 1.2) Then
            F.Offset(1, 0).Value = Q.Cell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Q
Next F
```

This has proven challenging, though. The intent was to iteratively check the values of Row1, as I have, and, if a value with the necessary criteria was found in Row2, place it beneath its correspondent in Row1.

The code has halted, however, due to a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".

How can the code be properly written so as to avoid such or similar errors?

Thank you much! And if you have any suggestions for improvement, feel free to advise.

Best,

Comment: You don't need the `.cell`  just `Q.Value`

Comment: Same with `F.Cell.value`, you don't need the `.Cell`  This is because VB will treat `F` as a range, (i.e. Range("A1"), then Range("A2"), as it iterates).  Therefore you don't need `.Cell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD Liamwilt,

AS per @Scott Cramer's answer.

Try this:

```
Sub t()

Dim F As Range
Dim Q As Range

For Each F In Range("A1:C1").Cells
    For Each Q In Range("A2:C2").Cells
        If Q.Value <= (F.Value + 1.2) Then
            F.Offset(1, 0).Value = Q.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Q
Next F

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments and previous answer show you how to fix the Run-time error

To get the end result you can use code like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub hSort()
    Dim row1 As Range, c1 As Range, cr1 As Double
    Dim row2 As Range, c2 As Range, cr2 As Double
    Dim tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set row1 = .Range("A1:D1")
        Set row2 = .Range("A2:D2")
        For Each c1 In row1
            For Each c2 In row2
                If IsNumeric(c1) And IsNumeric(c2) And c2.Column <> c1.Column Then
                    cr1 = Round(c1, 1)
                    cr2 = Round(c2, 1)
                    If cr2 <= cr1 + 1.2 And cr2 >= cr1 - 1.2 Then
                        tmp = row2.Cells(, c1.Column)
                        row2.Cells(, c1.Column) = c2
                        c2 = tmp
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Row1    68.39817    70.79805    73.1977
Row2                73.68835    68.88472
```

[image: hSort]

Comment: so, what we have so far seems to be working, but only to a point. first, i should explain that my rows of data do not just extend from A to D, but instead EG to IB. i also wish to compare "EG1:IB1" to each row individually down to and including "EG48:IB48" (47 comparisons). the principals are the same, but just required for a larger set. when I run your code, it sorts correspondents well for the first 4 or 5 cells, but then proceeds to erase large swaths of data thereafter and, toward the end, mismatch the number sets by a large margin. do you know why this might be happening? ty!

Comment: The answer illustrates the approach to the inital challange and works for the sample data you posted. Now you'll have to extrapolate and make it fit your requirements. You'll need to dynamically find the last row and column with data. If you're not sure how to do it, please accept one of the answers for this question, and open a new question to providing the test data in a link to a file so others will be able to guide you or adjust the code

Comment: I will take further action. However, on the topic of your response, might you know what it is within your code that does not allow the program to function as desired beyond the first 5 to 8 cells per row? I do not wish to run the program once for the entire sheet. I do want to run it once per each row combination. A dynamic search for the last cell with data may be necessary, but if you have accounted for cells possibly being set to nothing, and specified the row range to be searched, why might it be deleting a great deal of the cells' data beyond the first 5 to 8 rows? Just curious.

Comment: I'd have to test it using the same data - if you provide a file it can be implemented so that it will sort each row from EG2:IB2 to EG48:IB48 based on the values in cells EG1:IB1